# Tensorflow logits to one_hot Encoding

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have applied full_connected layer in tensorflow which gives me output of `[batch_size, 200, 15]`. `200` is the number of tokens in my sentence.

I am creating a tag (out of 15 tags) for each token in a sentence of 200 words. Now, my ground labels can be like `[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`. It means that the tag for this token can have two possibilities. Now if the model predict tag and it is possible tag in label, the loss should be zero.

For calculating, i did as in the code below. But it cant be optimized as the error is that there are gradients.

Is there a better way to do this ?

I guess the error is because of `tf.argmax()` as by doing thing the connection between loss and previous model is broken.

Another question is this. If you apply softmax layer after fully connected layer, your output is like `[0.5,0.3,0.05,0.15]`. is there a way that i can convert this into `[1,0,0,0]` ?

```
with tf.name_scope('loss'):
for i in range(200):
    print('in losses')
    labels = tf.reshape(han.input_y[:,i,:], [64, 15])
    logits = tf.reshape(han.out[:, i, :], [64, 15])
    logits_max = tf.argmax(logits,-1)
    depth = 15
    one_hot = tf.contrib.layers.one_hot_encoding(logits_max, depth)
    mul = tf.math.multiply(labels, one_hot)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.subtract(1.0, tf.reduce_sum(mul, 1, keepdims=True)))


    losses.append(loss)

losses = tf.reshape(losses, [-1, 200])
cost = tf.reduce_mean(losses)
```